# XSLT copy child node value to parent based on condition in parent and child

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

if `Orderitem`->`name` is 'Desktop' then copy the `price` from the `value` in `listofspareparts` where `name` is 'spare2' in `spareparts1`.

Input:

```
<listoforders>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>120</price>
        <listofspareparts>
            <spareparts1>
                <name>spare1</name>
                <value>140</value>
            </spareparts1>
            <spareparts1>
                <name>spare2</name>
                <value>130</value>
            </spareparts1>            
        </listofspareparts>
    </orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

Output should be:

```
<listoforders>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>130</price>
        <listofspareparts>
            <spareparts1>
                <name>spare1</name>
                <value>140</value>
            </spareparts1>
            <spareparts1>
                <name>spare2</name>
                <value>130</value>
            </spareparts1>                
        </listofspareparts>
    </orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

XSLT-1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>    
    <xsl:strip-space elements=""/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@">         
        <xsl:copy>             
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="price[../Orderitem[name='Desktop']"> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="value[../../listofspareparts/spareparts1[name='spare‌​2']]" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your XML is not well-formed because there is an inconsistency `<Orderitem>` vs. `</orderitem>`. So I chose to name this element `<Orderitem>`.

Your XPaths were pretty close and just needed a little fine-tuning. Just look at the differences. You need to always take into account the current node from where things develop relative to - which is called an axis.

> An axis defines a node-set relative to the current node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="price[../name='Desktop']"> 
    <price>
      <xsl:value-of select="../listofspareparts/spareparts1[name='spare2']/value" />
    </price>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is as desired.

Comment: Hi,@zx485 thanks, ../ is to access parent element i.e one level above and ../../ is for two levels above isnt it, but both  `name` and `listofspareparts` are siblings to `price`, how is the node position evaluated please? Out of context,If i use // vs .// is there a difference?

Comment: @Krish: The standard axis is to select children of the current node, so if your current node is `price` an expression `name` would be searched for as a child of `price`. So `../` selects the _sibling_ axis meaning all siblings of the current node (e.g. `name` and `listofspareparts`).

Comment: Regarding your second question: `//` selects nodes everywhere in the document(_relative to root_) and `.//` selects all child-nodes of the current node (_relative to current_).

Comment: Thanks. But I have used ../ and  ../../ to refer parent and grand parent respectively to solve a problem. As per your comment and code snippet the same  can be used to child and grand child as well ? You understood my confusion?

Comment: Well, no. You can't refer to children that way. In XML _every_ node has _exactly_ one parent but can have _several_ children. Hence you have to name the child you want to select (e.g. `listofspareparts`) - or select them all with `.//`. But the parent is always _unique_ and can be selected with `../`.